# JavaScript code to place activity indicator to a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the following code(no my own code) to load image to a css element (called cell) and to display an activity indicator.

```
var cell = document.createElement('li');
cell.textContent = this.labelForIndex(index);
var indicator = new NKActivityIndicator(); 
indicator.init(10,100,20,"white");
indicator.show(); 
indicator.spin();
$(cell).css("background-image", "url("+iconImage+")");
```

Now i want to place the indicator in the middle of the cell.this line of code `indicator.init(10,100,20,"white");`define the position width and color of indicator. I want to place it int the mid of cell.Any kind to response?

Comment: is it absolutlty positioned?

you can calculate the all thing cant you?
i mean: if you have cell width and the indicator width
you can position it in the middle.

substract the width of the indicator from the width of the cell
then divide by 2 and then give that position to the left of the indicator.
same thing about height

Comment: Actually calculation does not fact here...i can do it easily:)..but how i can get the position height width of cell??

Comment: $(cell).width() will give you its width
and $(cell).height() will give you its height

Comment: Thanks....why not u post it as answer??

Comment: why didnt you wait untill ill post this as answear before you accepted someone elses answear?

Comment: i actually saw the answer first and then saw ur comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/) or [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset) to retrieve the position of the cell and with the use of .height() and .width(), you can place the component in the middle of the cell.

Comment: It seems in the code you have just created the element. Did you attach the element to DOM?

Comment: If you have some UL element with id "container", you can use $("#container").append(cell)

Answer (score 1):

like all our talk in the comments:

all you need is $(cell).width() and  $(cell).height()

and not .position() or .offset() , not this time...

Comment: use firebug for firefox to go over the element and see its width.

maybe its not in the right float.

maybe you need to give it some css like:

display:block; float:left; position relative (if the element inside of it is positioned absolutly)

Comment: Hi,

.ad-carousel-view .cells > li {
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
        padding-top: 16px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: red;
   
 
      }
i think this will set the property...